# Regex to Match Inner find

Tags: html, .net, regex

I'm trying to match some html list tags `<ol>...</ol>` and `<ul>...</ul>` using .NET regex. I can match any or both of them using

```
<(ol|ul)( )?>.*</( )?\1>
```

but only if there isn't another of the same list down the line.

For example, this will get two hits:

```
<ol>this is the first list</ol>...<ul>this is the second list</ul>;
```

but this will only get one hit:

```
<ol>this is the first list</ol>...<ul>this is the second list</ul>...<ol>this is the third list</ol>
```

I feel like I need to replace the `.*` in the middle of my expression but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry, I guess should have mentioned (@aliteralmind) that I am specifically looking for `<ol>` and `<ul>` tags (and their closing tags), and both types will definitely contain `<li>...</li>` elements within.

Comment: don't use regexp to parse html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture all lines in an HTML list, you can use this:

```
<(ol|ul)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wSvgZRDtS6EJLTEK)

This requires "dot-matches-all". Capture group two contains all lines. The question mark is required after `.*` in order to go up to the *first* closing tag.

(For some reason, this isn't working in Debuggex, but it does work in [RegexBuddy](http://regexbuddy.com) for Perl.)

Comment: I added an edit to explain why this solution won't work in my case.

Comment: If you only want `ol` and `ul` tags, then just use `<(ol|ul)[^>]*>([^<]+)</\1>`.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't match when there are other tags within, such as `<li>` and `<b>`

Comment: Thanks! I changed the first group to (ol|ul) and it seems to do what I want.